# Modify JSON fields type

Tags: json, list, types, ansible

I have a list which contain data in JSON format:

```
[
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 2.080901628850305",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 13.581080423266766",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 7.848993362528565",
                "cpu_limits": " 0.0",
                "cpu_request": " 0.0",
                "dc_name": "db",
                "delta_cpu_limits": "  2.522309007407407  ",
                "delta_cpu_request": "  2.080901628850305  ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -493.33203125  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -493.89189276897764 ",
                "max_cpu": " 2.522309007407407",
                "max_memory": " 18.66796875",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 512.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-1",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            },
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 12.842575355202916",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 8.329453915867436",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 0.17931347295084302",
                "cpu_limits": " 0.0",
                "cpu_request": " 0.0",
                "dc_name": "redis",
                "delta_cpu_limits": "  1044.5020826481482  ",
                "delta_cpu_request": "  12.842575355202916  ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -501.12109375  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -503.6705460841326 ",
                "max_cpu": " 1044.5020826481482",
                "max_memory": " 10.87890625",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 512.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-1",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            },
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 2.0510519901995226",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 13.58236662375085",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 7.85209673059425",
                "cpu_limits": " 300.0",
                "cpu_request": " 200.0",
                "dc_name": "db",
                "delta_cpu_limits": " -297.6661470962963 ",
                "delta_cpu_request": " -197.94886067161377 ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -488.47265625  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -493.8901778349989 ",
                "max_cpu": " 2.333852903703715",
                "max_memory": " 23.52734375",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 306.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-10",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            }
]
```

I want to sort them with Ansible but all the fields are strings and the sort is not working correctly obviously. To do that, I'm doing this:

```
- name: divide json by resource
  set_fact:
    cpu_list: "{{ data_json.list|sort(attribute='max_cpu')| list }}"
```

I would like to know if there is a way to modify the fields in the json from string to float before doing the sort, that wait I'm sure the sort will be working nicely.

Thanks in advance for your help, regards!

Comment: you could check this one.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/52648

Comment: I was trying with `version_sort` but it does not accept attributes as `sort` does

Answer (score 0):

Convert the strings to numbers and create the list *data_update*

```yaml
  data_update: "{{ data_json.list|
                   json_query('[].{max_cpu: to_number(max_cpu)}') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  data_update:
  - max_cpu: 2.522309007407407
  - max_cpu: 1044.5020826481482
  - max_cpu: 2.333852903703715
```

Update the list of dictionaries and sort by the attribute

```yaml
  data_sorted: "{{ data_json.list|
                   zip(data_update)|
                   map('combine')|
                   sort(attribute='max_cpu') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  data_sorted:
  - avg_cpu: ' 2.0510519901995226'
    avg_cpu_deviation: ' 0.0'
    avg_memory: ' 13.58236662375085'
    avg_memory_deviation: ' 7.85209673059425'
    cpu_limits: ' 300.0'
    cpu_request: ' 200.0'
    dc_name: db
    delta_cpu_limits: ' -297.6661470962963 '
    delta_cpu_request: ' -197.94886067161377 '
    delta_memory_limits: ' -488.47265625  '
    delta_memory_request: ' -493.8901778349989 '
    max_cpu: 2.333852903703715
    max_memory: ' 23.52734375'
    memory_limits: ' 512.0'
    memory_request: ' 306.0'
    namespace: voting-app-10
    replicas: ' 1.0'
  - avg_cpu: ' 2.080901628850305'
    avg_cpu_deviation: ' 0.0'
    avg_memory: ' 13.581080423266766'
    avg_memory_deviation: ' 7.848993362528565'
    cpu_limits: ' 0.0'
    cpu_request: ' 0.0'
    dc_name: db
    delta_cpu_limits: '  2.522309007407407  '
    delta_cpu_request: '  2.080901628850305  '
    delta_memory_limits: ' -493.33203125  '
    delta_memory_request: ' -493.89189276897764 '
    max_cpu: 2.522309007407407
    max_memory: ' 18.66796875'
    memory_limits: ' 512.0'
    memory_request: ' 512.0'
    namespace: voting-app-1
    replicas: ' 1.0'
  - avg_cpu: ' 12.842575355202916'
    avg_cpu_deviation: ' 0.0'
    avg_memory: ' 8.329453915867436'
    avg_memory_deviation: ' 0.17931347295084302'
    cpu_limits: ' 0.0'
    cpu_request: ' 0.0'
    dc_name: redis
    delta_cpu_limits: '  1044.5020826481482  '
    delta_cpu_request: '  12.842575355202916  '
    delta_memory_limits: ' -501.12109375  '
    delta_memory_request: ' -503.6705460841326 '
    max_cpu: 1044.5020826481482
    max_memory: ' 10.87890625'
    memory_limits: ' 512.0'
    memory_request: ' 512.0'
    namespace: voting-app-1
    replicas: ' 1.0'
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data_json:
      list:
        [
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 2.080901628850305",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 13.581080423266766",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 7.848993362528565",
                "cpu_limits": " 0.0",
                "cpu_request": " 0.0",
                "dc_name": "db",
                "delta_cpu_limits": "  2.522309007407407  ",
                "delta_cpu_request": "  2.080901628850305  ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -493.33203125  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -493.89189276897764 ",
                "max_cpu": " 2.522309007407407",
                "max_memory": " 18.66796875",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 512.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-1",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            },
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 12.842575355202916",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 8.329453915867436",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 0.17931347295084302",
                "cpu_limits": " 0.0",
                "cpu_request": " 0.0",
                "dc_name": "redis",
                "delta_cpu_limits": "  1044.5020826481482  ",
                "delta_cpu_request": "  12.842575355202916  ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -501.12109375  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -503.6705460841326 ",
                "max_cpu": " 1044.5020826481482",
                "max_memory": " 10.87890625",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 512.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-1",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            },
            {
                "avg_cpu": " 2.0510519901995226",
                "avg_cpu_deviation": " 0.0",
                "avg_memory": " 13.58236662375085",
                "avg_memory_deviation": " 7.85209673059425",
                "cpu_limits": " 300.0",
                "cpu_request": " 200.0",
                "dc_name": "db",
                "delta_cpu_limits": " -297.6661470962963 ",
                "delta_cpu_request": " -197.94886067161377 ",
                "delta_memory_limits": " -488.47265625  ",
                "delta_memory_request": " -493.8901778349989 ",
                "max_cpu": " 2.333852903703715",
                "max_memory": " 23.52734375",
                "memory_limits": " 512.0",
                "memory_request": " 306.0",
                "namespace": "voting-app-10",
                "replicas": " 1.0"
            }
        ]

    data_update: "{{ data_json.list|json_query('[].{max_cpu: to_number(max_cpu)}') }}"
    data_sorted: "{{ data_json.list|zip(data_update)|
                                    map('combine')|
                                    sort(attribute='max_cpu') }}"
        
  tasks:
        
    - debug:
        var: data_update
    - debug:
        var: data_sorted
```